Splunk DB Connect and Snowflake Integration Error
Following  snowflake splunk db connect integration blog I have installed the Splunk DB Connect app (3.15.0) and the Splunk DXB Add-on for Snowflake JDBC (1.2.1).
When creating the identity in Splunk (matching the user created in Snowflake) this works fine, however creating the connection fails to validate (after trying for approximately 4-5 minutes) and gives me the following non-descript error:
connection string:
jdbc‌‌‌‌:snowflake://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=SPLUNK_USER&db=SNOWFLAKE&role=SPLUNK_ROLE&application=SPLUNK
This appears to hit some sort of timeout for the JDBC driver.
Added by default role, database, stanza to role still no luck.

I have got the solution. The problem is  OSCP Driver is connecting to an HTTPS endpoint without OCSP based Certificate Revocation checking as it could not obtain a valid OCSP Response to use from the CA OCSP responder.
In order to verify this, search index=_internal sourcetype=dbx_server. Is anyone able to see error above mentioned then edit the configuration of jdbc connection string and append
insecureMode=true

at the end that will resolve the issue.

Thanks a lot for the finding.
I have to fallback to a username / password authentication but initially tried with a key pair authentication but there are always a message as the private key is invalid.
Did you experiment a connection with a private key ?
